# Node/MongoDb JSON empty array bug

Tags: node.js, mongodb, driver

I recently upgraded to Node 5.4 and MongoDb 2.1.4 Driver for Node and I have the following problem :

I have a file called buildings.json containing something like this :

```
{
    "military_base": {
        "type": "military",
        "level": 0,
        "maxLevel": 25,
        "upgrade": true,
        "targetEnvironment": [],
        "timeUntilBuilt": 0,
        "costCoef": 0.4,
        "requiredResearches": [
          "foo#4",
          "bar#1"
        ],
        "requiredResources": [
          "cash",
          "metal",
          "palladium"
        ],
        "inProgress": 0,
        "queue": []
    },
    "aqua_center": {
        "type": "industrial",
        "level": 0,
        "maxLevel": 25,
        "upgrade": true,
        "targetEnvironment": [
          "ocean",
          "snowy"
        ],
        "timeUntilBuilt": 0,
        "costCoef": 0.7,
        "requiredResearches": [
          "lorem#10",
          "ipsum#3"
        ],
        "requiredResources": [
          "cash",
          "cristal"
        ],
        "inProgress": 0,
        "queue": []
    }
}
```

Now, I want to insert this document into a mongo database:

```
let buildings = require( "buildings" );
...
collection.insertOne( { foo: buildings }, callback );
```

If the first `"targetEnvironment"` array is empty, nothing is inserted, the callback is not called and there is no error. But if it's filled, all is fine, the callback is called and the document is correctly inserted...
I must admit that I don't know if the problem is related to Node or the MongoDb Driver...

Can someone help me, please ?

Comment: Did this same insert work before you upgraded?

Comment: Yes, I used Nodejs v0.12 and MongoDb Driver v1.4.

Comment: Can you log the error or turn on debug logs for your `mongod`?

Comment: There is no error. :(

Logs :
2016-01-22T17:24:15.638+0100 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:49892 #92 (1 connection now open)
Repeated 5 times.
2016-01-22T17:24:15.683+0100 [conn96] end connection
Repeated 5 times.
2016-01-22T17:26:23.780+0100 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:66 virt:253
2016-01-22T17:26:23.780+0100 [clientcursormon]  mapped:160
2016-01-22T17:26:23.780+0100 [clientcursormon]  connections:0

Comment: Seems like it's a driver issue then.  I would check on the `#mongodb` irc channel on [freenode](https://webchat.freenode.net/) or create an issue in the [MongoDb Node Driver repo](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native).

Comment: Okay, thank you very much !

Comment: Sure. Make sure to post the answer as an answer to your own question once it's resolved so it will help other people that may experience this problem.

Comment: @metame : I changed the values of costCoef properties from float to interger and it worked perfectly.... ! Is it a bug of the driver ?
So I deduced : when inserting large numbers like timestamp or float numbers, the insert operation will fails.

Comment: Nice. Post that as an answer and give a short code example of how you made it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh... As I have a 64bit Windows, I installed 64bit nodejs version and the problem came from here... with 32bit, there is no error ! :o

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const mongodb = require( "mongodb" );
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
const ObjectID = mongodb.ObjectID;

MongoClient.connect( "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test", function( err, db ) {
    if ( err ) {
        throw err;
    }

    var collection = db.collection( "test-insert" );
    collection.insertOne( test, ( err, obj ) => {
        if ( err ) {
            throw err;
        }

        console.log( obj.insertedId );

        db.close();
    } );
} );

var test = {
    "military_base": {
        "type": "military",
        "level": 0,
        "maxLevel": 25,
        "upgrade": true,
        "targetEnvironment": [],
        "timeUntilBuilt": 0,
        "costCoef": 0.4,
        "requiredResearches": ["foo#4", "bar#1"],
        "requiredResources" : ["cash", "metal", "palladium"],
        "inProgress": 0,
        "queue": []
    },
    "aqua_center": {
        "type": "industrial",
        "level": 0,
        "maxLevel": 25,
        "upgrade": true,
        "targetEnvironment": ["ocean", "snowy"],
        "timeUntilBuilt": 0,
        "costCoef": 7,
        "requiredResearches": ["lorem#10", "ipsum#3"],
        "requiredResources" : ["cash", "cristal"],
        "inProgress": 0,
        "queue": []
    }
};
```

If I try to insert this document, it will not be inserted because of the first costCoef property is a floating number. It will also fail if it's a large number like timestamp.

Comment: Oh so are you saying that inserting a floating number will fail no matter what?  That definitely shouldn't happen.  Definitely seems like a possible bug.

Comment: One way around it would be to convert your floats to strings before inserting, then casting them back to Numbers/floats on retrieval (if you had to do something with them)

Comment: Yes, that's the issue.
I have a lot of code which use timestamp and floating numbers with the database, I don't want to rewrite 10.000 lines... :(